# Range of sum of Normal Distribution.

Tags: normal-distribution

May be its silly question but I was just wondering is there any way to find out the absolute range of sum of values of Random normal distribution of N numbers with mu and sigma as mean and Std. Dev. ?

And what will be effect on the range with changing N , mu and Sigma ?

Comment: Are you aware of the range of distribution of a single normal random variable?

Comment: @Hima Depends, if they are independant, it's $]-\infty,+\infty[$, but otherwise it may be more complicated. For example if $X$ is normal and $Y=X$ if $|X|\leq1$ and $Y=-X$ if $|X]>1$ (so that $Y$ is also normal), then the range of $X+Y$ is obviously $[-2,2]$.